# SAS code Proc rank with groups option to SQL conversion

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I am new to SAS and struggling to convert the below piece of code to SQL.

```
proc rank data = input (where = (limit_assort = 1)) out = assort_rank  groups=3;
    var assort;
    ranks assort_rank;
run;
```

I tried in sql by using the below one but not matching with the SAS output.

```
Percentile_Cont(0.3) Within Group (Order by assortment) As assortment_rank
```

In SAS output, i can see a column "Rank for variable assort"with 0,1&2 based on the groups=3 option. But not sure how to handle it in SQl.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? What database software are you using SQL with?

Comment: we are using nzsql (Netezza).

Comment: In SAS output, after running the above proc there is an extra column with Rank for variable assort - it is randomly dividing the observation in 3 groups (0,1,2).